# Components in the WinForms are not visible

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: Scaling_Warning_message]
All the components in the WinForms are visible in the design but when i ran the project in Visual studio and open that form then some components present at bottom of the form are not visible.
Tried rescaling the visual studio also tried to change the DOCK, LOCATIONS but none of them worked out for me.
Attached is the image of the bottom part of the screen which is missing when the project is ran via VS.
[image: Bottom_part_of_the_form]

The save, recalc and that info is not visible when I ran the project.

Comment: It appears you're not designing at 100% scale. Visual Studio issues a warning when you don't. Try not to ignore it -- Those Controls at the bottom of your Form should be child of a container (e.g., a Panel) docked to the bottom. The Buttons should be the anchored to Bottom or Top and Right, the other to Bottom or Top and Left -- Make your app DpiAware (`PerMonitorV2`) if it's not already. You need to specify the .NET version you're targeting

Comment: When you have seen the scaling warning have you also clicked the "help me decide" link?  It will tell you about the whys and its implications. Many questions will be answered there.

Comment: @Jimi if am not wrong i think you are referring at [Scaling_Warning_message][1] 
But when i restarted the Visual Studio with 100% scaling then components at the bottom(Save,recalc and that info) it's not visible even in the Design also , previously atleast they were visible at the design and not when i ran the project.

Comment: You should design in 100% then scaling at runtime should work mostly. Because upscaling is easier then downscaling. But if you have already designed in some greater factor you need to first fix the design problems by hand. Visual Studio does not help you here. To put it also somewhat bluntly. Winforms is a somewhat ancient technology it somehow runs on current OSes but don't expect it to be glitch free. The scaling behavior is one of those problems.

Comment: Visual studio has a bug where windows sometimes are not rendered when system wide resolution scaling is enabled. I opened an issue with them some years ago, but they don't want to fix it. You can force redraw when you detach that pane and scale it. However you only see part of the code, then it's a different issue. Have you tried opening the file in a different tool like notepad? Or could be that the code is just not there, and there's something wrong in your design

Comment: Well, you have to resize the Form in the designer after you have set the scale -- Not that designing at 100% scale is not mandatory to achive a correct layout, it just helps to get it right if you're new to the platform, hence its behavior in this department -- As noted, it's important that you get used to nested containers to host your Controls. That becomes kind of mandatory when the Form needs to be scaled to accomodate the scale of different screens

Comment: @Ralf no it's not that simple. Visual studio itself still has it's fundaments in ancient technology and so has a number of bugs from then. This scaling issue pops up in things like settings and property screens. I use latest technologies and still encounter it every now and then. And it's weird that visual studio, a Microsoft product doesn't properly support Microsoft Windows scaling...